# Understanding errors in attempts to skip N iterations of a loop

Tags: python, loops, continue

I want to skip 3 iterations of a loop, and made various attempts.

I would like to know how to do it correctly, but more than that, I would like to understand why each of these attempts fail in different ways. Please can you explain?

These numbers are only examples. How I really use it. Your list might be `["donut", "carrot", "apple", "apple", "burger"]` and when you get to `carrot` you discover that you have to skip two items (a dog eats two of your food items) so that your iterations should be `["donut", "apple", "burger"]`. So you don't know in advance which iterations to skip. You just get a condition and number of iterations to skip.

**NUMBER 1.** This does not skip any iterations at all.

```
l = list(range(10))

for i in l:
    if i == 3:
        for j in range(3):
            continue
    print(i)
```

**NUMBER 2.** This skips some iterations, repeats an iteration, mixes up some iterations, really a total mess.

```
l = list(range(10))

for i in l:
    
    if i == 3:
        l.pop(i)
        l.pop(i+1)
        l.pop(i+2)

    print(i)
```

**NUMBER 3.** This skips only one iteration.

```
l = list(range(10))

for i in l:
    if i == 3:
        continue
        continue
        continue
    print(i)
```

**NUMBER 4.** This gives syntax error.

```
l = list(range(10))

for i in l:
    if i == 3:
        continue 3
    print(i)
```

**NUMBER 5.** This skips all remaining iterations.

```
l = list(range(10))

countdown = 0

for i in l:

    if i == 3:
        countdown = 3

    if countdown > 0:
        cuntdown = countdown - 1
        continue

    print(i)
```

What is going wrong in each case, and what else can I try?

Comment: So, *which* 3 iterations of the loop do you want to skip? How do you want the output to be different to: `for i in range(10): print(i)`?

Comment: I want to skip 3, 4, and 5, so that it writes 0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8, and 9.

Comment: But I don't know in advance which iterations I will skip. If I get to skip iteration condition then I want to skip some iterations. The `i == 3` condition is only an example.

Comment: Also I prefer if the number of iterations to skip is in a variable. I don't really like `continue continue continue` because it fossilizes that the number to skip will be 3. It could be different.

Comment: Is this clear now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code for number 5 would work except, amusingly, you have written `cuntdown` instead of `countdown` in your second `if` statement.

Here is why the others do not work:

**Number 1:**
`Continue` only moves your code onto the next iteration of the loop that is currently being executed. In this example, it simply moves onto the next loop of `for j in range(3):` rather than `for i in l` so no iterations of the original loop are skipped.

**Number 2:**
Here you are popping elements of a list whilst iterating over it. This is not really ever advisable as you will end up with an index error or something similar.

**Number 3:**
This only skips one iteration because once your first `Continue` is executed, the loop immediately moves onto loop with `i == 4` and the remaining `Continue`s are never executed.

**Number 4:**
`Continue 3` is not correct syntax for use with `Continue`

Comment: Thank you. I've corrected 5 ... oh dear ... and all is working, and the other explanations are really helpful. In C this couldn't happen because you get compile error.

Comment: Okay number 4 was a bit desperate but you never know unless you try.

Comment: Number 2 is even worse than that. Not only is it modifying a list while iterating over it, but also `l.pop(i); l.pop(i+1); l.pop(i+2)` will not succeed in removing three consecutive items from a list. They would have to be removed in the reverse order, or use the same index `i` each time.

Comment: Another simple solution (given that we are dealing here with a list that can be indexed, rather than a generic iterable) would be to loop using an index variable that is initialised and incremented by hand, together with a `while` condition. Then if you want to skip some iterations, you just add the required extra increment to the index variable (and also `continue` to skip the current iteration).